# GitLab OAuth access token validity

Tags: oauth, gitlab

Does anyone know what the expiration period of an OAuth Access Token on GitLab is?

It's at least 12 hours (from experience), but I would like to know for sure so I don't refresh the token unnecessary.

PS: **GitLab** ... it would be very convenient if the expiration is simply returned when getting/refreshing token (PS: the documentation states that "expires_in":  is returned ... BUT IT ISN'T)

Comment: Here is the GitLab issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21745 tracking this bug.

Comment: @steinybot 4 years ago I have asked 2 years it is still open ... I would say will not happen

Comment: It says accepting merge requests so sure it won't happen if no one bothers to contribute a patch.

Comment: @ColonelPanic it took only 4 years to implement ... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from https://forum.gitlab.com/t/missing-expires-in-in-the-token-response/1232/2:

> Gitlab uses Doorkeeper for oauth.
>
> The Doorkeeper wiki has an ariticle "Customizing Token Expiration" > https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Customizing-Token-Expiration2
>
> This wiki tells us a configuration "access_token_expires_in". I > searched in gitlab source code and found it sets to nil.
>
> This meas the 'access_token' will never expire.

Also, this is from https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/50d66f5ece57dcfbe074d97703691a8d3c38f4ac/config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb#L42:

```
 # Access token expiration time (default 2 hours).
 # If you want to disable expiration, set this to nil.
 access_token_expires_in nil
```

Comment: Yes it never expires ... so refreshing is useless. They sometimes return a refresh token .. and you can refresh the token with the refresh token. But in case you are unable to read the new token (after refresh) for whatever reason - you lock yourself out, as a new refresh token is generated on the refresh call. This is a bit of a broken design, so don't refresh.

Comment: Hello I see today that they are no oauth2 access_token expiration.
Is it a security issue ?

Comment: @Benito103e sure it is ... having one and the same token for an extended period is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

On GitLab, OAuth ["access tokens expire in two hours"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html#expiring-access-tokens).

> Access tokens expire in two hours which means that integrations that use them must support generating new access tokens at least every two hours.

In older versions, OAuth applications could opt-out of access token expiry.

> The ability to opt-out of expiring access tokens was deprecated in GitLab 14.3 and removed in 15.0. All existing integrations must be updated to support access token refresh.

Answer (score 0):

2016: It should be **8 hours** by default:

[`lib/gitlab/o_auth/session.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/91fa250038e9182988319f088fb84741b6e2efc9/lib/gitlab/o_auth/session.rb) mentions:

```
Rails.cache.write("gitlab:#{provider}:#{ticket}", 
                   ticket, expires_in: Gitlab.config.omniauth.cas3.session_duration)
```

In [gitlab.yml](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/12dd0f62012c6df8bd67abc2d9c5c54bd82366f7/config/gitlab.yml.example#L410-L412), you have:

```
# SSO maximum session duration in seconds. Defaults to CAS default of 8 hours.
# cas3:
#   session_duration: 28800
```

---

2022: the [Expiring access tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html#expiring-access-tokens) documentation mentions:

- no more  opt-out of expiring access tokens since GitLab 15.0 (June 2022)
- Access tokens expire in **two hours** which means that integrations that use them must support generating new access tokens at least every two hours.

Comment: It isn't ... I have done some test calls yesterday around 16:00 ... and again with the same token today at: 10:00, so more than 18h in total. I have looked up different implementations of GitLab API integrations and everyone has some different value if any.

Comment: @Drejc What your `gitlab.yml` says about `session_duration`?

Comment: I'm using the public API (gitlab.com/api/v3)